# Find rows that have a field which is a substring of the search string

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a table like so:

```
id      |    value
-------------------
1       |     food
2       |     foot
3       |     barfoo
4       |     bar
5       |     baz
```

Using postgres I want to find all of the rows where the value field matches from the start of the search field. Sort of like `SELECT * FROM table where 'foo' ilike value%`

Searching for 'foo' would return food and foot but not barfoo.

I think this should be easy but I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

shouldn't the comparison be switched

```
where value ilike 'foo%'
```

**Edit**

- Changed to Case Insensitive "ilike", per original example.

*So many SQL dialects, so little greymatter storage space.*

Comment: You might want to change "like" to "ilike" though, to match the question.

Comment: thanks, you've answered the question correctly, I've just noticed that  I asked the wrong question though. Never mind.

Answer (score 0):

You have the arguments to [ILIKE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) the wrong way round:

```
SELECT * FROM table where value ilike 'foo%'
```